# Can't edit Definded step filters in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want add aop packages to improve debug experience,

so i go to Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering,

enable the "Use Step Filters" and add aop packages to the "Defined step filters",

[image]

When i click "apply and close" and reopen it,the packages of i added was disappear,

[image]

I don't know how edit it.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok,its seems like a bug,the settings work but they didn't show up ....,

Comment: The config file write to [workspace]/.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.prefs

Comment: Have the same problem with latest Eclipse 2022-03.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reported and fixed post-4.23 in Bug 576615  It affects a number of filter table views including Step Filters, Content Assist Favorites, and Type Filters.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576615

The fix is available in 4.24 M1 and has very recently been back-ported to the 4.23 maintenance branch after the JDT github migration.